# FullCalendar - MultiMonth - Nb of events per day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using FullCalendar 6.1.

I would like to know if there is a solution to display more than one event per day in a multiMonths view?

I tried dayMaxEventRows, and dayMaxEvents, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [event popover documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover), `dayMaxEvents` and related settings only apply to month, dayGrid and parts of the timeGrid view. It doesn't apply to the multi-month view, at the time of writing.

The only workaround for this I've found so far is to set the `multiMonthMinWidth` option. If you set a larger value, you can force the month grids to be large enough that each cell can accommodate multiple rows of events. After a bit of experimentation, in my demo at least, 600px was the smallest value which would cause this.

```
multiMonthMinWidth: 600
```

More info: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/multiMonthMinWidth

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwVjxwE

Comment: Ok thanks... But yes, it's way too big like this... :(

Comment: Maybe. But then, if it's much smaller, the extra events cannot physically fit into the space anyway. So I don't know what you are expecting the calendar or day cell to look like in that situation?

Comment: Well, I expected at least a bit more vertical space in rows, to fit at least 2 events...

Comment: Well to do that, you have to increase the overall size of the grid (unless you expect that the cells could be rectangular rather than square?). Maybe they could make the minimum size where it takes effect a bit smaller, I guess. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features if you want to suggest that.